# Rails js.erb file: undefined local variable or method `params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to access the `Request Parameters` from my `.js.erb` file in Rails 4.

```
(function(){
  this.quickDate = <%= params[:quick_date] || "All Time" %>;
  .....
})();
```

This is returning the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<#<Class:0x007faf83c92bf8>:0x007faf7e022508>
```

Can I not access the `Request Parameters` from a `.js.erb` file?

Comment: NO ... the js erb file is a template that will be used to render a response. You could do something like @q_date = params[:quick_date] in your controller and then have access to the new variable in your js.erb file.

Comment: @jjk hmm I just tried your suggestion and `@q_date` is `nil`

Comment: what is the value of params in your controller? How is the controller accessed? Some more information will help to answer your question.